# Is that a good practice to throw exception from controller

Tags: servlets, model-view-controller, exception, httprequest

Is that a good practice to throw exception from controller?

For instance we may throw **IllegalStateException** from some controller's method if Request hasn't some attribute.

Also for instance we may throw **IllegalArgumentException** from some controller's method if Request's parameter is not in appropriate format/range.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think so.  Who will handle it?  The client.  What does handling it mean?  Exceptions won't tell them what to do.  Better to change the UI to instruct them on what do to next.  You see this in every decent web UI that you use: the text box is highlighted and you're told what the proper range is.  What kind of experience would seeing a stack trace be?

So the controller should catch *all* exceptions and change the display accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a good idea to throw such exception to end user. Instead you may alert end user a meaningful error message which use can easily understand what is wrong.